# Handling validation in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to implement validation logic in angular 4 application. I need to stop the user from saving if any of the data is invalid.

If you see I am having `isMinValid` and `isMaxValid` function. I have declared two private variables `_isMinValid` & `_isMaxValid` fields and initializing it with true or false.

I am checking for the values of this variable in the Ok method which saves information.

The problem that I am facing is that `isMinValid` and `isMaxValid` function gets called for every row in the table hence if the next row is `true` then the private fields gets assigned the value accordingly. Hence the last value could be `true`. How do I fix this issue?

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items; let last = last; let item_IDX = index">
              <td *ngIf="!last">
                <click-input [classNames]="{'has-warning': !isMinValid(item,item_IDX), 'number' : true}">
                  <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" shortNumberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
                </click-input>
              </td>

              <td *ngIf="!last" class="text-right">
                <click-input [classNames]="{'has-warning': !isMaxValid(item,item_IDX), 'number' : true }">
                  <input [(ngModel)]="item.maxSize" required min="0" max="999999999999999" shortNumberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0">
                </click-input>
              </td>
</tr>


     private _isMinValid: boolean = false;
      private _isMaxValid: boolean = false;

      public ok() {
        if (this._isMinValid && this._isMaxValid) {
          this.data.domicileId = this.domicileId;
          this.data.domicileInfo = this.domicileInfo;
          this.hide(true);
        }
      }

  isMinValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
      this._isMinValid = true;
      return true;
    }
    let previousItem = this.domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items[item_IDX - 1];
    if (+currentItem.minSize !== +previousItem.maxSize) {
       this._isMinValid = false;
      return false;
    }
     this._isMinValid = true;
    return true;
  }


  isMaxValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
      this._isMaxValid = true;
      return true;
    }

    if (+currentItem.maxSize <= +currentItem.minSize) {
      this._isMaxValid = false;
      return false;
    }
    this._isMaxValid = true;
    return true;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, you want to make them true for the first index, then adding to your code: you can have a check if `_isMaxValid` and `_isMinValid` are already false, if so, then don't assign true to them.

```
isMaxValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
      this._isMaxValid = true;
      return true;
    }

    if (+currentItem.maxSize <= +currentItem.minSize) {
      this._isMaxValid = false;
      return false;
    }
    if (this._isMaxValid) {
        this._isMaxValid = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Do a similar thing for min valid.
Now, if you also want to check for the first element, then check the `item_IDX`along with `this._isMaxValid`. for example:

```
isMaxValid(currentItem: any, item_IDX: number) {
    if (+currentItem.maxSize <= +currentItem.minSize) {
      this._isMaxValid = false;
      return false;
    }
    if (item_IDX === 0) {
        this._isMaxValid = true;
    }
    else if (this._isMaxValid) {
        this._isMaxValid = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I just noticed. why are we checking if true and setting true again if (this._isMaxValid) {

Comment: Question?? This makes sure that if the flag has become false even once then it will not be set to true again. That's the basic idea. Your can obviously optimize it.